# Inline-block in FireFox overlaps boundary instead of overflowing

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firefox

I have a problem with FireFox rendering that I don't have in other browsers. I have a table cell that is resizable via the colResisable plugin. In my second cell I have two divs, one containing an unordered list and the other with a table. I'm not sure the contents of these div matters.

Both of these divs are styled as inline-block. The parent has nowrap for the whitespace in an effort to prevent the second inline-block from falling beneath the first. My intention is that the content would overflow the parent TD with a scrollbar.

This works correctly in IE, Safari and Chrome, but in FireFox the content overlaps on top of the border of the parent.

Here are two screenshots showing the difference:

[image: How this renders in Chrome]

[image: How this renders in FireFox]

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVNae/23/) that approximates this behavior, but I can't quite get it the same. Hopefully someone will see this and know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `display: inline-block` to `float: left`:

```
#content_1, #content_2 {
    ...
    float: left;
    ...
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xVNae/24/**

---

If you want to keep `display: inline-block` try changing changeing `border-collapse` to `inherit` for `table`:

```
table {
    border-collapse: inherit;   
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xVNae/25/**

Comment: Excellent! I have avoided floats in general, preferring inline-block, but in this case this does the trick. Thanks.